# ESP32 IDF Ble Gatt Server Example

Tags: esp32

I am trying to use esp32 IoT development framework. It is a bit complicated for me especially BLE examples. I am trying to understand gatts_service_table example but it has huge code inside and too hard for the first BLE APP. Is there any simple Ble example on IDF? I know kolbans libraries and I tried that but my aim is IDF. But to learn IDF I have to improve my programming skills first.

I want to create a profile. After add service inside, and characteristic. After creating my BLE architecture, send receive data with a phone app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BLE looks simple from the user's point-of-view but is quite complex under the hood.  It took me several months to wrap my head around it.

This example is organized much better than the example from Espressif (BlueDroid-based, it's what I'm using in my product):
https://github.com/eagi223/esp-idf_Bluetooth_Multi-Service

(vs. the Espressif example: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/bluedroid/ble/gatt_server_service_table )

BTW, Now NimBLE is available in ESP-IDF 4+, which is supposed to be more memory efficient and simple to use, but I haven't tried it yet.  https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/bluetooth/nimble/index.html

Answer (score 5):

The examples of nimble ble given in espressif documents are quite difficult to follow. It took me some time to understand nimble BLE use with esp32. After referring many other sources, I finally succeeded in its use.

So I have written a tutorial which I think is easier to follow than examples given in espressif documents.

https://github.com/Zeni241/ESP32-NimbleBLE-For-Dummies

Hope it will help someone.